# R Append list according to first column elements

Tags: r

I have two list, the first list stores information such as person's id , shopping dates, and shopping value.

```
person ID  date         Value 
a        2015-01-01     15
a        2015-02-15     150
b        2015-11-01     30
c        2015-12-21     45
```

The second list also contains the person ID as well as income information, such as

```
person ID  income         
a          1500
b          985
c          2110
```

What I want is to append the income information into the first list, like this

```
person ID  date         Value    Income
a        2015-01-01     15        1500
a        2015-02-15     150       1500
b        2015-11-01     30        985
c        2015-12-21     45        2110
```

How can I do that in R ?

Maybe it is a duplicated question, but I fail to find out what I want.

Comment: You haven't searched hard enough.  It's the most basic `merge()`

Comment: Thanks !!! I found it !!!